# How to fix this issue in safari " TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'link.click()')" using angular2 or Typescript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, safari, angular2-template

i have a template download which is working fine with Chrome,mozila and Opera but gives error with Safari, saying

`"TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'link.click()')"`

HTML:

```
<button class="btn" (click)="generateTemplate()">
<img src="../../assets/images/export.png"> Download Template(.csv)
</button>
```

Ts:

```
generateTemplate() {
var data = [{"CVR":'',
  "address":'',
  "financeEmail":'',
  "firstInvoice":'',
  "lastInvoice":'',
  "name":'',
  "phoneNumber":'',
  "postalCode":'',
  "salesEmail":''}]
  var options = { 
    fieldSeparator: ',',
    decimalseparator: '.',
    showLabels: true
  }
  var timestamp = new Date();
  var file_name = "template";
  new Angular2Csv(data,file_name,options);
}
```

Can anyone help please.